# Is it possible to dump an LXD container to a tgz archive?

Tags: lxd

I wonder if it's possible to dump a whole container to a tgz archive, so it can be bakuped or moved to another server. I know I can do it with an image, so I can pusblih the container as an image and dump it but would be nice to be able to do it directly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible first you need to publish your container that will create a local image and then you export that image this will create an archive

eg
lxc list on my machine

```
 TestContainer | RUNNING
```

Publish the Container

```
lxc publish TestContainer --alias TestContainerPublish --force
```

and export the image in curr dir

```
 lxc image export TestContainerPublish .
```

And than you are done

Comment: Yes, I know this method but if you read carefully my post I was asking to do this without publishing. Thanks anyway ;)